# Does Polymers template auto-binding break model property?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to use `<template is="auto-binding">` to use Polymer Expressions inside my template.

As for any other `<template bind>` I activate a template, by attaching model property, as described at [Polymer Docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html#activating-a-template)

My code looks as follows:

```
<template id="root"  is="auto-binding">
    List
    <ul>
    <template repeat="{{ item in list }}">
        <li>{{item.desc}}</li>
    </template>
    </ul>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var template = document.getElementById( "root" );

    template.model = {
      "list": 
          [{
            "desc": "first"
          }, {
            "desc": "second"
          }]
      };
</script>
```

JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/fibuc/1/edit), as you can see [here jsbin.com/fibuc/1/quiet](http://jsbin.com/fibuc/1/quiet) it does not work. (Chrome Canary, Chrome Stable, IE, Firefox).

It seems that, if I assign `list` directly to `template` it works: http://jsbin.com/fibuc/3/quiet

```
template.list = 
  [{
    "desc": "first"
  }, {
    "desc": "second"
  }, {
    "desc": "third"
  }];
```

What is really weird, it still works with `.model` if I delay attaching a bit: http://jsbin.com/fibuc/2/quiet

```
setTimeout( function () {
  template.model = {
    "list": 
      [{
        "desc": "first"
      }, {
        "desc": "second"
      }, {
        "desc": "third"
      }]
    };
  },1000);
```

Is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

---

**Edit**: If possible, I would like to keep the script unaware of way template was used: `<template bind>` or `<template is="auto-binding">`.
In my case script code is inside Custom Element [puppet-js](https://github.com/PuppetJs/Puppet-Js) that only provides data from server to given node, and the outer application is responsible to create templates.

Answer (score 4):

The best set of docs for `<template is="auto-binding">` are at http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#autobinding

The examples there illustrate setting the bound variables on the `<template>` directly, rather than going through the `model`. It's what you would do if you were using the template from within a Polymer element, and I believe the idea is to maintain that usage pattern rather than interacting with the `model` like you would with a non-`auto-binding` `<template>`.

That being said, if you do want to set the model, what seems to work is to do so after the `template-bound` event is fired—your `setTimeout()` was approximating that, but it's obviously cleaner to just listen for that event. Here's an example ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jagis/3/edit)):

```
  var template = document.getElementById("root");
  template.addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
    template.model = {
      "list": [
        {"desc": "first"},
        {"desc": "second"},
        {"desc": "third"}
      ]
    };
  });
```

**EDIT:** Looking at the [relevant source code](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-dev/blob/master/src/lib/auto-binding.js#L53), it appears that ignoring the `model` property of the `<template>` initially is intentional, and it gives some insight as to why setting `model` after `template-bound` works if you really want to do that.

Comment: The problem is that `template-bound` is not triggered for regular `<tempalte bind>`. I would like to keep code in script (which in fact is in a Custom Element [puppet-js](https://github.com/PuppetJs/Puppet-Js) ) be unaware of way outer app used template

Comment: I see two options: either try to detect what flavor of template your code is used in via something like `template.getAttribute('is') == 'auto-binding'`, or alternatively see if you can convince the Polymer maintainers to change the behavior and do something like `this.model = this.model || this` in the `createdCallback` for auto-binding templates. You can [file a bug](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-dev/issues) and see what they have to say.